# How to create a LaTeX template in Overleaf for Grading essays

Tags: templates, overleaf

I wish to create a LaTeX template for grading essays.

Once the student's essay is copy/pasted in the template, the teacher
could isolate parts of the text by either crossing them out, underlining or 
surrounding them, with commands that will be created like `\corrcross{}`, `\corrunder`, `\corrround`. A remark could then be added for every correction.

By intuition, I'd think that the best way for that would be to implement the footnote in a way that it would appear in between the lines of the essay.
I would appreciate any feedback on the whole process. I don't know where to begin.

Comment: You may want to consider the `changes` package: https://ctan.org/pkg/changes Here's an example on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/tracking-changes-in-latex-with-changes-package/fnpkpytjjwhj

Comment: I don't think that a LaTeX solution is the best idea here.

Comment: Thank you @LianTzeLim it seems that you already have created the exact template I was trying to make... I did not see when i went through the template database. Thanks for creating something for the non scientific community :D